# Upload binary image file using linkedin create share api gives null response using python code but curl command works

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, linkedin-api

Curl command below works perfectly but converted curl command into python code doesn't. However python code return status code 201 but response.text prints nothing.

FYI:  I am following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin).

Here is Working Curl Command:

```
curl -i --upload-file "/home/abhay/download.jpeg" --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxx" 'https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5122AQE4GSagETyxQA/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQK_YGFfk_crEwAAAWoGPkMNETNZnhoeCKKmD_CKYeasF1NHooQ7pdeZWA&app=5969925&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1DL2-qd0JrroI1'
```

Converted python code

```
upload_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5122AQE4GSagETyxQA/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQK_YGFfk_crEwAAAWoGPkMNETNZnhoeCKKmD_CKYeasF1NHooQ7pdeZWA&app=5969925&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1DL2-qd0JrroI1'
headers = {
    'accept' : 'application/json',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxx',
    # 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
}

image = open("/home/abhay/download.jpeg" ,"rb")
files = {'images_file': image }

response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, files=files)
print response.status_code
print response.text
```

Curl gives correct response:

```
HTTP/2 201 
date: Wed Apr 10 07:59:03 UTC 2019
server: Play
set-cookie: lang=v=2&lang=en-us; Path=/; Domain=api.linkedin.com
x-ambry-creation-time: Wed Apr 10 07:59:03 UTC 2019
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.linkedin.com
content-length: 0
x-li-fabric: prod-lsg1
x-li-pop: prod-tmu1
x-li-proto: http/2
x-li-uuid: FPDYGfsNlBXg+OFSZisAAA==
set-cookie: lidc="b=SB83:g=115:u=5:i=1554883143:t=1554953528:s=AQEVXPybFdnyKyPqSWbf_ax997ap-22S"
x-li-route-key: "b=SB83:g=115:u=5:i=1554883143:t=1554953528:s=AQEVXPybFdnyKyPqSWbf_ax997ap-22S"
```

Python code gives the following response

```
201 (status code)
None (response.text)
```

Can anybody help me out what I am missing out in python code? Thanks!

Comment: What does `print(response.content)` give?

Comment: response.content also print nothing(None) but following headers is getting printed.

`{'Content-Length': '0', 'X-Li-Pop': 'prod-tmu1', 'Set-Cookie': 'lang=v=2&lang=en-us; Path=/; Domain=api.linkedin.com, lidc="b=SB83:g=115:u=5:i=1554884960:t=1554953528:s=AQGAt3Q8z5wbWGxsA18EgmNE_cQ6_Qr1"', 'X-LI-UUID': 'xs03N6IPlBVgK3JDTisAAA==', 'Server': 'Play', 'X-LI-Route-Key': '"b=SB83:g=115:u=5:i=1554884960:t=1554953528:s=AQGAt3Q8z5wbWGxsA18EgmNE_cQ6_Qr1"', 'X-Li-Fabric': 'prod-lsg1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-ambry-creation-time': 'Wed Apr 10 08:29:21 UTC 2019', 'Date': 'Wed Apr 10 08:29:...
`

Comment: According to the headers for both Curl and your Python code, the `Content-Length` is zero. That means that there is no response body - which is probably by design. The fact that the status code is `201` indicates that the image was created successfully by the server.

Comment: @AbhayKumar Do not post your authentication token publicly...